# Substitute with sed

Tags: sed

I have a problem with a sed

I have an example:

```
‘texttexttexttext’,47384728,’147,65’,’texttexttext’
```

I want this, the same but in the value number, the dot.

```
‘texttexttexttext’,47384728,’147.65’,’texttexttext’
```

I wrote something but it’s not true:

```
sed -e s/[0-9]\,[0-9]/\./g
```

But the result is this:

```
‘texttexttexttext’,47384728,’14.5’,’texttexttext’
```

Can you help me? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Capture the digits before and after the comma.

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/g'
```

No need to backslash a comma, it has no meaning in sed. Also, dot is not special in the replacement part, so no backslash needed either.